# creating and assigning values to an array of structs in Julia

Tags: struct, julia

I would like to define a struct to hold a vector of 3 elements

```
mutable struct Coords
    r::Array{Float64,3} # essentially holds x,y,z coords
end
```

I now want to make an array of these structures, and give random values to the vector inside each structure.

This is where I fade out. I have tried a few things which I will describe, but none of them worked.

---

trial 1:

```
x = 10                            # I want the array to be of length 10
arrayOfStructs::Array{Coords,x}
for i=1:x
    arrayOfStructs[i].r = rand(3)
end
```

The error message is

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Array{C
oords,10}
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T<:Array}, ::AbstractArray) where T<:Array at array.jl:489
  convert(::Type{T<:AbstractArray}, ::T<:AbstractArray) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:1
4
  convert(::Type{T<:AbstractArray}, ::LinearAlgebra.Factorization) where T<:AbstractArray at C:\User
s\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\LinearAlgebra\src\factorization.jl:46
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] setindex!(::Array{Array{Coords,10},1}, ::Int64, ::Int64) at .\array.jl:769
 [2] getindex(::Type{Array{Coords,10}}, ::Int64) at .\array.jl:366
 [3] top-level scope at C:\Users\Zarathustra\Documents\JuliaScripts\energyTest.jl:68 [inlined]
 [4] top-level scope at .\none:0
in expression starting at C:\Users\Zarathustra\Documents\JuliaScripts\energyTest.jl:67
```

I don't get why it thinks there are integers involved.

I have tried changing the inside of the for loop to be

```
arrayOfStructs[i] = Coords(rand(3))
```

to no avail.

I have also tried initializing `arrayOfStructs = []`

Comment: Although, your comment has been removed, you can always construct your array using comprehensions (type will be inferred) similar to Python, see: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/index.html#Comprehensions-1

Please see the update to my answer.

Comment: This is just for timing. I have a realistic test problem, and I am putting julia up against python. In python I am using normal,numpy,numba,cython versions. I haven't implemented cython yet. Using only arrays, Julia is blowing numba out of the water, which is surprising. Numba for me, is 1 order of magnitude faster than regular python per for loop, which is a big speed up. But Julia seems to be 2 orders of magnitude faster per for loop.  Now I want to use an array of structs, rather than just array but can't even initialize... it is kind of funny :)After will be a struct of arrays.

Comment: I did get the array of structs working using your recommendation, hence the checkmark... I just find that everytime I change my approach to the probem, ie, the struct having an array of length 3, rather than 3 floats, or the struct having 3 arrays each of length N, it is always back to the drawing board. All of the examples for structs in Julia's docs are for trivial things.

Comment: This is a useful source for Julia, it has better examples than Julia's doc's

https://riptutorial.com/Download/julia-language.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`N` in `Array{T,N}` defines the dimensionality of the array, that is, an `N`-dimensional array of type `T`.

You are not defining an array of size 3 to hold `x`, `y`, `z` coordinates in your `struct` definition, instead you are defining a 3D Array, which does not suit your purpose.

Yet again, you just declare the type of `arrayOfStructs` to be a 10-dimensional array without *constructing* it. You need to define and construct your array properly before using it.

`Array` types in Julia does not have static size information. `Array` is a dynamic structure and does not suit your case. For array types with static size information you might want to take a look at [`StaticArrays.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl).

Here is how I would go with your problem.

```
mutable struct Coords
    x::Float64
    y::Float64
    z::Float64
end

x = 10 # I want the array to be of length 10
# create an uninitialized 1D array of size `x`
arrayOfStructs = Array{Coords, 1}(undef, x) # or `Vector{Coords}(undef, x)`

# initialize the array elements using default constructor
# `Coords(x, y, z)`
for i = 1:x
    arrayOfStructs[i] = Coords(rand(), rand(), rand())
    # or you can use splatting if you already have values
    # arrayOfStructs[i] = Coords(rand(3)...)
end
```

You might instead create an empty outer constructor for your type that initializes the fields randomly.

```
# outer constructor that randomly initializes fields
Coords() = Coords(rand(), rand(), rand())

# initialize the array elements using new constructor
for i = 1:x
    arrayOfStructs[i] = Coords()
end
```

You may also use comprehensions to easily construct your array.

```
arrayOfStructs = [Coords() for i in 1:x]
```

If you still want to use an `Array` for your field, you may define `r` as a 1D-array and handle the construction of `r` in your constructors.

You might want to take a look at the relevant sections in the documentation for `Array`s and `Composite Types`:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1

Comment: If the OP decides to use `StaticArrays`, a [`FieldVector`](https://juliaarrays.github.io/StaticArrays.jl/stable/pages/api.html#StaticArrays.FieldVector) might be the best option.